# SearchBarController Search bar hiding tableview cells in case of multiple autolayout constraint

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have two views in my view controller first one is uitableview and the second one is bottom fixed UIView. I have autolayout constraint set up for both views, the table is at top and the second one is fixed at bottom, in the table view I am adding search bar. On the view load everything renders fine but as soon as the search bar is made active, the first two cells slip under the navigation bar. If i remove the Bottom view and bottom constraint everything works fine.

Here is the sample code im running

```
self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero
                                                  style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80;
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = [UIView new];
    [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
    [self.tableView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.leading.trailing.top.mas_equalTo(self.view);
        make.bottom.equalTo(self.bottomToolBar.mas_top);

    }];

    self.definesPresentationContext = YES;


    self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;

    // Configure the search bar with scope buttons and add it to the table view header
    self.searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = @[@"Country",@"Capital"];

    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;

    self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
    [self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
```

Comment: try to set priority of that constraint and try it

Comment: use vertical hugging priority.